# Issue with integrating Stripe Checkout in ReactTS and .Net project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm working on a React TypeScript project with an ASP.NET backend for API services. I'm attempting to integrate Stripe Checkout following the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart). However, I'm encountering an error:

> 'The 'price' parameter should be the ID of a price object, rather than the literal numerical price. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#create-prices for more information about how to set up price objects

For additional details, I've employed the Context API for state management when users add products to their cart.

Here is my frontend code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useCart } from "../../context/cart-context";
import { Container, Button, Text, Group, Grid, Col, Divider } from "@mantine/core";
import { Image, Input } from "@mantine/core";
import { routes } from "../../routes";

export const CartPage = () => {
  const { cart, removeFromCart, updateCartItemQuantity } = useCart();
  const [isCheckout, setIsCheckout] = useState(false);

  const handleRemoveFromCart = (productId) => {
    removeFromCart(productId);
  };

  const handleQuantityChange = (productId, newQuantity) => {
    const itemToUpdate = cart.find((item) => item.product.id === productId);

    if (itemToUpdate) {
      updateCartItemQuantity(itemToUpdate.product.id, newQuantity);
    }
  };

  const calculateTotalPrice = (item) => {
    return item.product.price * item.quantity;
  };

  const calculateCartTotalPrice = () => {
    return cart.reduce((total, item) => total + calculateTotalPrice(item), 0).toFixed(2);
  };

  const handleCheckout = async () => {
    const cartItems = cart.map((item) => ({
      PriceId: item.product.price,
      quantity: item.quantity,
    }));

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost:44312/api/checkout/create-session", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(cartItems),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("here is data",data);

      window.location.href = routes.home;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating checkout session:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>Your Cart</h2>
      {cart.length === 0 ? (
        <Container style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Empty Cart</Text>
          <Text>Add products to your cart</Text>
        </Container>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Grid gutter="lg" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            <Col span={3}>
              <Text>Product</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col span={3}>
              <Text>Quantity</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col span={3}>
              <Text>Price</Text>
            </Col>
            <Col span={3}>
              <Text>Action</Text>
            </Col>
          </Grid>
          <Divider my="sm" />

          {cart.map((item, index) => (
            <Container key={item.product.id}>
              <Grid gutter="lg">
                <Col span={3}>
                  <Group align="middle">
                    <Image
                      src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${item.product.images[0].data}`}
                      alt="Product Image"
                      width={80}
                    />
                    <Text>{item.product.name}</Text>
                  </Group>
                </Col>
                <Col span={3}>
                  <Group align="middle">
                    <Button onClick={() => handleQuantityChange(item.product.id, item.quantity - 1)}>-</Button>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      value={item.quantity}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleQuantityChange(item.product.id, parseInt(event.target.value))
                      }
                      min={1}
                    />
                    <Button onClick={() => handleQuantityChange(item.product.id, item.quantity + 1)}>+</Button>
                  </Group>
                </Col>
                <Col span={3}>
                  <Text>${(item.product.price * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</Text>
                </Col>
                <Col span={3}>
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveFromCart(item.product.id)}
                    variant="outline"
                    color="red"
                  >
                    Remove
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Grid>
              {index < cart.length - 1 && <Divider size="xs" style={{ marginTop: '16px', marginBottom: '16px' }} />}
            </Container>
          ))}
          <Container style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bolder" }}>Total Price: ${calculateCartTotalPrice()}</Text>
            <Button variant="outline" color="yellow" onClick={() =>setIsCheckout(true)}>
              Checkout
            </Button>
          </Container>
          {isCheckout && handleCheckout()}
        </>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export interface GetProduct {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    productCategories: string|null;
    price: number;
    status:string|null;
    images: Array<{ id: number; data: string }>;
  }
```

Here is the API I've developed, following the documentation:

```
using Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Stripe;
using Stripe.Checkout;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

[Route("api/checkout")]
[ApiController]
public class CheckoutApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("create-session")]
    public ActionResult CreateCheckoutSession([FromBody] List<CartItem> cartItems)
    {
        var domain = "https://localhost:44312"; 
        var stripeSecretKey = "sk_test_51OB0nSH2tjloydjcsI57ff00Lc2Mkmpf";

        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = stripeSecretKey;

        
        var options = new SessionCreateOptions
        {
            LineItems = cartItems.Select(item => new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                Price = item.PriceId.ToString(), 
                Quantity = item.Quantity,
            }).ToList(),
            Mode = "payment",
            SuccessUrl = domain + "?success=true",
            CancelUrl = domain + "?canceled=true",
        };

        var service = new SessionService();
        Session session = service.Create(options);

        return Ok(new { sessionId = session.Id });
    }
}

public class CartItem
{
    public string PriceId { get; set; } 
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I modified the price to a string as the `SessionLineItemOptions` datatype for the price is a string.

I do not possess a `stripePriceId` for my product.

Comment: I recommend removing your test secret key from your code snippet above. While it's a test key, you should still keep it secret/out of public forums.

Comment: @LauraT It is just random key i have deleted this key from my api key.

Comment: Got it. I suggest logging the value of `Price` you're using in `SessionCreateOptions`. Stripe expects a string ID in the format of `price_123abc...`. Based on the error message, it looks like you're passing a numerical amount/literal price of the item. Since you have a price ID, you should pass this instead.

Comment: @LauraT I tried but go the same error and i don't have stripePriceId in my product. Can you help me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Oh, I totally misread your message; you mentioned you don't have a Price ID. While it's possible to use inline price data for Checkout, any prices and/or products you create inline cannot be reused. If you anticipate charging multiple customers for the same item at the same amount, you should create a Product and a Price and use `SessionLineItemOptions` to pass the Price ID. If you would rather create prices inline, you should use `SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions` to pass currency, amount, and product (or use `SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions` to create an inline Product).